# Make edit funcion without conflict on edit booking django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

i make bus reservation system which have filtering to prevent double booking on same bus at same date..

here's the code on forms.py :

```
class BookingEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = '__all__'

        widgets = {
            'idbooking': forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'id_booking', 'style':'text-transform: uppercase'}),
            'BusId': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'id': 'bus_id'}),
            'start' : forms.DateInput(format=('%Y-%m-%d'), attrs={'type': 'date', 'class': 'form-control', 'required':'true'}),
            'end_date' : forms.DateInput(format=('%Y-%m-%d'), attrs={'type': 'date', 'class': 'form-control', 'required':'true'}),
            }
    
    def clean(self):
        start = self.cleaned_data['start']
        end_date = self.cleaned_data['end_date']
        BusId = self.cleaned_data['BusId']

        res_all = Booking.objects.all().filter(BusId=BusId)
        for item in res_all:
            if start <= item.start and item.start <= end_date or start <= item.end_date and item.end_date <= end_date:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Bus already reserved on same date!")
```

views.py :

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def edit_book(request, pk):
    booking = Booking.objects.get(idbooking=pk)
    booking_forms = BookingEditForm(instance=booking)
    customer_forms = CustomerForm(initial={
            'phone': request.GET.get('phone'),
            'name': request.GET.get('name')
        })
    if request.method == 'POST':
        booking_forms = BookingEditForm(request.POST)
        if booking_forms.is_valid():

            idbooking = booking_forms.cleaned_data['idbooking']
            BusId = booking_forms.cleaned_data['BusId']
            start = booking_forms.cleaned_data['start']
            end_date = booking_forms.cleaned_data['end_date']

            Booking.objects.filter(idbooking=booking).update(
                idbooking=idbooking,
                BusId=BusId,
                start=start,
                end_date=end_date,
            ),
            return redirect('booking-list')

        else:
            print(booking_forms.errors)
        
    context = {
        'cform': customer_forms,
        'form': booking_forms,
    }

    return render(request, 'booking/create_book.html', context)
```

Now, i need help to run this filtering on edit function, because that works on create booking
but when i try implement on edit, its not work

I think there is something to do on `idbooking`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the `instance` attribute for update actions. Change your clean method as below. It should work

```
def clean(self):
    start = self.cleaned_data['start']
    end_date = self.cleaned_data['end_date']
    BusId = self.cleaned_data['BusId']
    if hasattr(self,'instance'): # if this raises error try if self.instance: instead
        res_all = Booking.objects.exclude(BusId=self.instance.BusId).filter(BusId=BusId)
    else:
        res_all = Booking.objects.all().filter(BusId=BusId)
    for item in res_all:
        if start <= item.start and item.start <= end_date or start <= item.end_date and item.end_date <= end_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Bus already reserved on same date!")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.. but sorry still not work.. when i submit, program still think they have booking on same date

Comment: It would have been more helpful if you update the question with the view's code where you've handled the form.

Comment: hi.. i already update that.. hope its get more clear.. thank you

Comment: i made few change on views.. now its work.. thanks